# Replacing domains of e-mail addresses with just one domain

Tags: shell, sed

I would like to edit a file containing a set of email ids such that all the domain names become generic.

```
Example,
peter@yahoo.com,
julie@hotmail.com,
philip@gmail.com

to
peter@generic.com,
julie@generic.com,
philip@generic.com
```

I used the following sed command,

```
sed '/@/,/.com/ s//generic/' filename.txt
```

here the sed replaces '@' with 'generic and .com with 'generic' and not the content in between @ and .com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
sed 's/@[^,]*/@generic.com/'
```

This will replace everything after the "@" until the first comma with generic.com, thereby fixing the domain, and leaving the ending comma in tact.

Since you seem to have some confusion, ranges (`/regex/,/otherregex/`) select a number of lines, not positions within a line.

Comment: @user1428900 You can reuse the `.com` by doing `sed 's/@[^.]*/@generic/' inputfile`